Chrome extension: injected value disappears after content script runs
I am writing a chrome extension (Manifest V3) where I am trying to let the content script know what the tab ID is by setting a window property (because I use it a few times later). I am doing this using executeScript() in the following manner in my background.js:
function setTabIDInContent(id) { 
  window.tabId = id; }

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (tab.url?.startsWith("chrome://")) return undefined;

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabId },
      args: [tabId],
      world: "MAIN",
      func: setTabIDInContent
    });
    
});

In my content script, I have a listener defined in the following manner:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {  
        sendResponse({tabId: window.tabId, 
          info: 'other stuff'});
        
});

I am observing this peculiar behavior:

Right after a page loads, typing window.tabId in the console window prints the correct value.
However, after the content script runs - specifically, after I send a message to it from the background script, and it invokes the listener, window.tabId becomes undefined. Putting a breakpoint in the content script's listener method, I verified that window.tabId is indeed undefined during execution. After the listener finishes execution, when I go back to the console window and type out window.tabId, I see it has become undefined there was well.

Why would this happen and what might I do to persist this value?

Your function is injected into the MAIN world of the page, not in the default world of content scripts, which is why your onMessage listener doesn't see it.
Content scripts by default run in an isolated JS world, so the availability of the value in console depends on which JS world it uses. You can change the context before running a command in console:

Note that executeScript may run in the old contents of the tab before it navigated to the new URL. To avoid it you can use documentId in executeScript's target, but that requires chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted instead of onUpdated.
A better solution in this case is to use sender.tab.id in chrome.runtime.onMessage listener instead of storing tabId.

Thanks. Like I mentioned, this erasure seemed to be caused by just the content script executing (I definitely didn't inspect an element). About the context switch itself, doesn't the world="MAIN" param already handle that?
As per the docs, sender.tab.id populates a value only when another tab has opened a new tab. I had checked this property myself as well, sender.tab.id doesn't exist, but sender.id does, which however points to the extension's ID (mentioned in the same doc).

I've missed world in your code and updated the answer. Looks like you have a content script in the default (isolated) world that uses onMessage. It can't see the main world by design. 1) Why did you specify world? 2) You are reading the documentation incorrectly about sender.tab.id and apparently you mean your onMessage listener in the content script, but I mean the background script where sender.tab.id is present in messages sent from a tab's content script, so you don't need to include it.
